# Using multiprocessing in Python ends in ImportError

Tags: python

I'm trying to run simple programs from Python doc using `multiprocessing`, however I always get errors like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                               
  File "Poolexample.py", line 1, in <module>
    from multiprocessing import Pool
ImportError: cannot import name Pool
```

or similarly, `cannot import name Process`. Anyone knows why does Python send me such errors?

Comment: Probably you have a file with the name `multiprocessing.py` that shadows the Python module.  Remove or rename that file.  (BTW, it's no suprise you can't import `Porcess`...)

Comment: The multiprocessing module was added in Python 2.6.

Comment: What do you get if you `import multiprocessing` and then `print multiprocessing.__file__`?

Comment: I had a file named `threading.py` and I was getting attribute error while importing `multiprocessing` module. Took me a while to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: Be sure to delete the .pyc files after you've renamed the multiprocessing.py to something else, or it will still complain (as it did for me :D)

Answer (score 1):

As [@ahojnnes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308391/ahojnnes) said, [`multiprocessing`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0371/) was introduced [in Python 2.6](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-371-the-multiprocessing-package). So, be sure to use Python 2.6+ if you need this module with painless integration.

However, you could use [python-multiprocessing](http://code.google.com/p/python-multiprocessing/), which is a backport of `multiprocessing` for Python 2.4 and 2.5.

Comment: Run `python --version` to find out which version you're using

Comment: or `import platform; print platform.python_version()`